# About pinpoint apm installation Why don't start-collector.cmd, start-testapp.cmd, start-web.cmd files exist

Tags: installation, hbase, aws-pinpoint

I cloned a folder in github, installed hbase, and ran the cmd file as it was in the official document. And I put the jar file in the location. Why do I get an error saying that I couldn't connect with zookeeper? Can anyone tell me the exact installation method? And the official document says to run start-collector.cmd, start-testapp.cmd, start-web.cmd files**your text**, but I can't find them Please let me know how to find i

i try to install the old version.I also installed the quick start version